# apache is not getting installed on linux mint

Tags: linux, apache, linux-mint

I'm a newbie in linux and having problem with installing apache2. I've installed and uninstalled apache2 once. Used [this](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-apache2-on-ubuntu-debian.html) article to uninstall apache2. After that, it's not getting installed/working. So far these are the things I've tried as root user.

```
> sudo apt-get install apache2
```

> ....... apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3).
>   .......

I can't find any directory named apache2 though using the following command.

```
> whereis apache2
```

I'm not getting any response in the browser with `http://localhost/` since apache2 was not installed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apache2 is a metapackage that just selects other packages. If you installed apache by installing that package, you just need to run this to clean up the automatically selected packages:

> sudo apt-get autoremove

if that doesn't work, you might have installed one of the dependents manually. You can target all the apache2- packages from space and nuke the lot:

> sudo apt-get remove apache2

You can do the following two tests to confirm apache has been removed:

1. which apache2 - should return a blank line
2. sudo service apache2 start - should return apache2: unrecognized service

Then to install apache2 you need to excute commands in this order :-

**

> 1. sudo apt-get update
> 2. sudo apt-get install apache2

**
 3. Press Y and hit Enter to continue, and the installation will proceed.
Next you need to set your ServerName globally in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf as following :-
**

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

**
Add this line to the bottom of apahce2.conf file ( if you dont know your server domain you can use your server ip address) then Save and close the file when finished:-
**

> ServerName server_domain_or_IP

**
Next, check for syntax errors by typing:
**

> sudo apache2ctl configtest

**
if everything is ok you need to restart apache service to make changes effective as folowing:-
**

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

**

Answer (score 0):

I think u should remove completely with:
apt-get remove apache2 and
apt-get purge apache2.
After do that try again installing